# Constructing the graph of a function

Tags: integration, limits, functions

I need to solve the following problem:

> Consider the function $g(x) = \ln(x^{2}) + 2$. Construct the functions graph $f(x)=\int g(x)\:\mathrm{d}x$ considering the integration constant equal to zero. To construct the graph determine the domain, the roots, the intervals of growth and degrowth, the extremes, the concavity and asymptotic lines.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $g(x)=2 \ln(x) + 2$. To find the roots of $f(x)$, you can integrate by parts to find $f$ explicitly.

The derivative of $f$ is $g=2(\ln(x)+1)$, and from this you can find where the function is increasing or decreasing and where the critical points lie.

Differentiating again gives $f^{\prime \prime}(x)=\frac{2}{x}$, which lets you find the concavity.

You can use the  explicit form of $f$ to find the asymptotes.